# How can I change the whiteBalanceGains value?

Tags: ios, avcapturesession

I am getting the error:

```
- whiteBalanceGains contain an out-of-range value. Red, green, and blue gains must be in the [1, maxWhiteBalanceGain] range
```

How can I determine maxWhiteBalanceGain range?

```
AVCaptureDevice *device =
[AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
AVCaptureWhiteBalanceTemperatureAndTintValues temperatureAndTint = {
    .temperature = 8000,
    .tint = 146,
};

[device deviceWhiteBalanceGainsForTemperatureAndTintValues:temperatureAndTint];

[device setWhiteBalanceModeLockedWithDeviceWhiteBalanceGains:[device deviceWhiteBalanceGainsForTemperatureAndTintValues:temperatureAndTint] completionHandler:^(CMTime syncTime) {

 }];
```

Answer (score 4):

rom apple developer doc

"Note though that some temperature and tint combinations yield out-of-range device RGB values that will cause an exception to be thrown if passed directly to `setWhiteBalanceModeLockedWithDeviceWhiteBalanceGains:completionHandler:`. Be sure to check that the red, green, and blue gain values are within the range of [1.0 - maxWhiteBalanceGain]."

So, first, you have to get the white balance gains

```
AVCaptureWhiteBalanceGains wbGains = [device deviceWhiteBalanceGainsForTemperatureAndTintValues:temperatureAndTint]
```

Than, check if `wbGains.redGain, wbGains.blueGain, wbGains.greenGain` in range of [1 ... maxWhiteBalanceGain].

`maxWhiteBalanceGain` is a property of the `AVCaptureDevice` object.